# I want to test my api that is running in VM vagrant in host OS using IP adress :

Tags: python, python-3.x, vagrant, virtual-machine, bottle

- the server is running in VM with vagrant :

vagrant@ubuntu-xenial:/vagrant/email_api$ python3 emailapi.py
Bottle v0.12.17 server starting up (using WSGIRefServer())...
Listening on http://127.0.0.1:8080/
Hit Ctrl-C to quit.

but when i use IP to access to api i get :

Could not get any response
There was an error connecting to .
Why this might have happened:
-The server couldn't send a response:
Ensure that the backend is working properly
-Self-signed SSL certificates are being blocked:
Fix this by turning off 'SSL certificate verification' in Settings > General
-Proxy configured incorrectly
Ensure that proxy is configured correctly in Settings > Proxy
-Request timeout:
 Change request timeout in Settings > General

*vagrant file :

```
config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8080, auto_correct: 
true

 config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.10"
 config.vm.network "public_network"
```

Comment: What configuration is your Vagrant VM? Did you create it or is it something you downloaded? Did you try modifying the settings it suggested?

Comment: I changed some:
-config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8080, auto_correct: true
-config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.10"
-config.vm.network "public_network"

Answer (score 0):

you should run your bottle app on `0.0.0.0` to export it to "other" machines

```
app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=80, reloader=True, debug=True)  # ...
```

Answer (score 0):

For me i proxy pass the internall server with nginx works well just make a configuration on nginx like this

```
server{
   listen 85;
   listen [::]:85;
   server_name rsshistory.com;
   location / {
      proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000/;
   }
}
```

On the vagrant file, dont turn on all of that just do this

```
# Create a forwarded port mapping which allows access to a specific port
# within the machine from a port on the host machine and only allow access
# via 127.0.0.1 to disable public access
# config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8080, host_ip: "127.$

# Create a private network, which allows host-only access to the machine
# using a specific IP.
config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.11"
```

Now you can access to the bottle server true 192.168.33.11:85